# PySpark difference between printing a result and writing it to the database

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, etl

I'm facing a weird issue when performing some transformations using PySpark dataframes.

I want to randomly select a name when that field is null in the dataframe. That column is being populated by another dataframe using a join first.

The code performing the join and selecting the required columns:

```py
# Reading the current replica of UserMaster table
user_master_replica_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=read_replica_url, table="dbo.\"UserMaster\"", properties=properties)
user_master_replica_df = user_master_replica_df.select("UID", "Name", "LastName")
user_master_replica_df = user_master_replica_df.withColumnRenamed("UID","UID_2")

# Reading and Masking UserMaster table
user_master_df = spark.read.jdbc(url=read_url, table="dbo.\"UserMaster\"", properties=properties)
user_master_df = user_master_df.drop("Name", "LastName")
user_master_df = user_master_df.filter(user_master_df['HospitalID'] != '4156')

user_master_df = user_master_df.join(user_master_replica_df, user_master_df['UID'] == user_master_replica_df['UID_2'], how='left')
user_master_df = user_master_df.drop("UID_2")
user_master_df = user_master_df.select("UID", "Name", "LastName", "Gender", 
            "Unit", "Birthday", "Age", "Height", "UUID", "DeviceTokenID", "DeviceType", 
            "CreatedDate", "UpdatedDate", "IsActive", "AcceptPolicy", "AcceptPolicyDate", 
            "AppVersion", "HospitalID", "timedifference", "installationdate", "loginId")
# print(user_master_df.filter( (user_master_df.UID == 1) & (user_master_df.Name.isNull()) ).show())
print(user_master_df.filter( (user_master_df.UID == 5) & (user_master_df.Name.isNotNull()) ).show())

user_master_df = name_masking(user_master_df)
```

This is the code that defines the name_masking function:

```py
def name_masking(df):
    m_first_names_list = ['James', 'Robert', 'John', 'Michael', 'William', 'David', 
        'Richard', 'Joseph', 'Thomas', 'Charles', 'José', 'Luis', 'Carlos', 'Juan', 
        'Jorge', 'Santiago', 'Benjamín', 'Leif', 'Bjorn','Kai', 'Amir', 'Ibrahim', 
        'Nadir', 'Saad', 'Samir']
        
    f_first_names_list = ['Marie', 'Patricia', 'Jennifer', 'Linda', 'Elizabeth', 
        'Barbara', 'Susan', 'Jessica', 'Sarah', 'Margaret','Sofía', 'Valentina', 
        'Isabella', 'Sara', 'Victoria', 'Natalia', 'Nicole', 'Karin', 'Kelsye', 'Lisabeta', 
        'Asha', 'Daria', 'Moira', 'Safira', 'Zareen']
        
        
    m_first_names = list(map(lambda c: F.lit(c), m_first_names_list))
    f_first_names = list(map(lambda c: F.lit(c), f_first_names_list))

    df = df.withColumn('Gender', F.trim(F.col('Gender')))
    
    # df = df.withColumn('Name', F.when(df.Gender == 'Male', quinn.array_choice(F.array(m_first_names))).otherwise(quinn.array_choice(F.array(f_first_names))))

    print(df.filter(df.UID == 5).show())

    # df = df.withColumn('Name', F.when( (df.Gender == 'Male') & (df.Name.isNull()), quinn.array_choice(F.array(m_first_names)))
    #     .when((df.Gender == 'Female') & (df.Name.isNull()), quinn.array_choice(F.array(f_first_names)))
    #     .otherwise(df.Name))
    
    # df = df.withColumn('Name', F.when(df.Gender == 'Male', 'Pepe').when(df.Gender == 'Female', 'Pepa').otherwise('Nada'))
    
    df = df.withColumn('Name', F.when(df["Name"].isNull(), 'Peppppa').otherwise(df.Name))
    
    return df
```

This is the output for the prints statements:

```
-------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ | 5|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 171|63823da5003f7b7f|fSWWzZnMCrw:APA91...| 1|2019-06-04 15:58:...|2019-06-05 04:13:...| false| true|2019-06-04 15:58:...| null| 3135| null|2019-06-04 17:57:00|
    null| +---+-------+--------+----------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ None
    +---+-------+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ |UID| Name|LastName|Gender|Unit|Birthday|Age|Height| UUID| DeviceTokenID|DeviceType| CreatedDate| UpdatedDate|IsActive|AcceptPolicy| AcceptPolicyDate|AppVersion|HospitalID|timedifference| installationdate|loginId| +---+-------+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ | 5|Peppppa| null|Female| 0| null| 0| 171|63823da5003f7b7f|fSWWzZnMCrw:APA91...| 1|2019-06-04 15:58:...|2019-06-05 04:13:...| false| true|2019-06-04 15:58:...| null| 3135| null|2019-06-04 17:57:00| null| +---+---
    ----+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ None
    +---+-------+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ |UID| Name|LastName|Gender|Unit|Birthday|Age|Height| UUID| DeviceTokenID|DeviceType| CreatedDate| UpdatedDate|IsActive|AcceptPolicy| AcceptPolicyDate|AppVersion|HospitalID|timedifference| installationdate|loginId| +---+-------+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ | 5|Peppppa| null|Female| 0| null| 0| 171|63823da5003f7b7f|fSWWzZnMCrw:APA91...| 1|2019-06-04 15:58:...|2019-06-05 04:13:...| false| true|2019-06-04 15:58:...| null| 3135| null|2019-06-04 17:57:00| null| +---+-------+--------+------+----+--------+---+------+----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ None
```

So there you can see that for the 3 prints statements for the UID 5 the name is the same. Also before writing the dataframe to the database the name for the UID =5 is "Peppppa", but if I query the databse once the job has finished I the following:

[image: Result image]

Can anyone help me with this? I don't know what else to try.

Result of printing the head of the user_master_df before calling the name_masking function

[image]

```
+---+-------+--------+----------+----+-------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ |UID| Name|LastName| Gender|Unit| Birthday|Age|Height| UUID| DeviceTokenID|DeviceType| CreatedDate| UpdatedDate|IsActive|AcceptPolicy| AcceptPolicyDate|AppVersion|HospitalID|timedifference| installationdate|loginId| +---+-------+--------+----------+----+-------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ | 28|Peppppa| null|Male | 1|1994-06-10 00:00:00| 0| 170|04D89FAD-4A67-428...|e_iUb9kEUZI:APA91...| 2|2019-06-10 14:00:...|2019-06-10 14:00:...| true| true|2019-06-10 14:00:...| null| 0| null| null| null| | 29|Peppppa| null|Female | 0|1988-12-07 00:00:00| 30| 175| 2b5bd01a6b401097|cgGD4AL3dZ4:APA91...| 1|2019-06-10 19:46:...|2019-06-10 19:46:...| true| true|2019-06-10 19:46:...| 10| 0| 120|2019-06-10 21:45:00| null| | 30|Peppppa| null|Male | 1|1995-06-11 00:00:00| 0| 170|46CCD95A-2631-430...|ecShlfAdaEE:APA91...| 2|2019-06-11 04:28:...|2019-06-11 04:28:...| true| true|2019-06-11 04:28:...| null| 0| null| null| null| | 33|Peppppa| null|Male | 2|1990-06-09 00:00:00| 0| 187|67A8D991-E424-478...|dJkiTe18SYo:APA91...| 2|2019-06-11 05:04:...|2019-06-11 05:04:...| true| true|2019-06-11 05:04:...| null| 2803| 240|2019-06-11 00:00:00| null| | 93|Peppppa| null|Male | 0| null| 0| 180| 062b26c7fdab16f3|e9kUuTWPtGU:APA91...| 1|2019-06-25 13:56:...|2019-06-30 11:39:...| false| true|2019-06-25 13:56:...| 13| 3132| 120|2019-07-30 13:06:00| null| |151|Peppppa| null|Female | 0|1959-08-10 00:00:00| 59| 168| c0bd06c09e791b78|eGOjv2yYpcg:APA91...| 1|2019-07-18 09:01:...|2019-07-18 09:01:...| true| true|2019-07-18 09:01:...| 14| 3477| 120|2019-07-18 11:01:00| null| |171|Peppppa| null|Male | 0|1995-03-08 00:00:00| 24| 186| f07da2b6dbd83626|co_5BLw4bd4:APA91...| 1|2019-07-25 11:24:...|2019-07-25 11:24:...| true| true|2019-07-25 11:24:...| 14| 3132| 120|2019-07-25 13:23:00| null| |200|Peppppa| null|Male | 1|1994-08-21 00:00:00| 0| 170|5C322C57-9657-4A4...|dqKYdlU7U2E:APA91...| 2|2019-08-21 12:58:...|2019-08-21 12:58:...| true| true|2019-08-21 12:58:...| 207| 0| null| null| null| |208|Peppppa| null|Female | 1|1985-08-11 00:00:00| 0| 162|735053D4-5327-468...|f-qKvSVtQ-E:APA91...| 2|2019-08-26 13:56:...|2019-08-26 13:56:...| true| true|2019-08-26 13:56:...| 100| 0| 60|2019-08-26 00:00:00| null| |221|Peppppa| null|Female | 0|1986-09-22 00:00:00| 32| 168| a7d603c509a07827|diKB68lta7I:APA91...| 1|2019-09-05 08:59:...|2019-09-05 08:59:...| true| true|2019-09-05 08:59:...| 14| 0| 120|2019-09-05 10:59:00| null| |224|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 164| d05900f705e9f108|f2eUDaooYZA:APA91...| 1|2019-09-07 08:24:...|2019-09-07 08:28:...| false| true|2019-09-07 08:24:...| null| 3512| null|2019-05-20 10:22:00| null| |232|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 44| 160| 374af787fd742b9a|eLGIfYgGe9g:APA91...| 1|2019-09-11 09:45:...| 2020-08-17 19:04:09| false| true|2019-09-11 09:45:...| 14| 3475| 60|2019-09-11 14:25:00| null| |248|Peppppa| null|Female | 1|1970-04-14 00:00:00| 0| 163|9F8DA210-3D93-428...|eDMDuAzBxMc:APA91...| 2|2019-09-17 12:55:...|2019-09-17 12:55:...| true| true|2019-09-17 12:55:...| 100| 3132| 60|2019-09-17 00:00:00| null| |262|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 163| da91286657dc0640|dmzKz6NP4PQ:APA91...| 1|2019-09-24 16:33:...|2019-09-24 16:39:...| false| true|2019-09-24 16:33:...| null| 3132| 120|2019-09-24 18:36:00| null| |269|Peppppa| null|Male | 0|1983-09-12 00:00:00| 36| 161| 6d49d91a120ac5dc|clb9a5u-2mw:APA91...| 1|2019-09-27 09:47:...|2019-09-27 09:47:...| true| true|2019-09-27 09:47:...| 14| 0| null|2019-09-26 20:51:00| null| |271|Peppppa| null|Female | 0|1984-09-27 00:00:00| 35| 154| d7dfaa0239802bac|fCf3WE4Sumw:APA91...| 1|2019-09-27 11:57:...|2019-09-27 11:57:...| false| true|2019-09-27 11:57:...| null| 3665| null|2019-09-27 13:57:00| null| |295|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 160| 248f08754970d633|dlMW_XiICEI:APA91...| 1|2019-10-03 19:13:...|2019-10-03 19:17:...| false| true|2019-10-03 19:13:...| null| 0| null| null| null| |300|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 162| 85591f0bdc66801d|dPeL7DU_5wc:APA91...| 1|2019-10-06 08:09:...|2019-10-24 19:25:...| false| true|2019-10-06 08:09:...| 14| 0| 120|2019-09-26 10:07:00| null| |325|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 0| 160| 567c59fbef76336a|exhpxo76BU4:APA91...| 1|2019-10-15 12:18:...|2019-10-15 17:17:...| false| true|2019-10-15 12:18:...| 14| 3132| 120|2019-10-15 19:20:00| null| |347|Peppppa| null|Female | 0| null| 24| 185| 9d58ad727c1c85ee|eNm1AkLfZQ8:APA91...| 1|2019-10-23 07:49:...| 2020-02-09 08:54:46| true| true|2019-10-23 07:49:...| null| 3474| 60|2019-10-21 15:14:00| null| +---+-------+--------+----------+----+-------------------+---+------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------+--------------+-------------------+-------+ only showing top 20 rows 
None
```

**UPDATE**
So I've discovered that the error is happening when spark writes the df to the database, I don't know why but the Name column is being filled with null values in the database.
I've tried using a DynamicFrame and write it to the database and it's working ok, but when writing a DynamicFrame to the database it doesn't give you the option to overwrite the data that is something that I need to do.

Comment: Could you also add a print or head of usermaster DF before it goes through name_masking.

Comment: @vivekveeramani I'll edit the post adding the result of printing the head before calling the name_masking function.

Comment: [No images please](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/10669875)

Comment: You want `df.show()`, not `print(df.show())`, by the way. That'll give you a much better format

Comment: @OneCricketeer I'm running this in AWS Glue, that's why is not pretty formated. Thank you for your recommendation anyway!